# Can't run Espresso test: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/http/impl/client/HttpClientBuilder;

Tags: android, android-espresso, ui-testing

In my app/build.gradle:

```
android {
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myproject.android"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 6
        versionName "0.0.8"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    }

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.7.0@aar') { transitive = true; }

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha03'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.1.0-alpha03'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0-alpha03'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.chauthai.swipereveallayout:swipe-reveal-layout:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.8.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.yuyh.json:jsonviewer:1.0.6'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$KOTLIN_VERSION"

    implementation project(':common')

    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:$ESPRESSO_VERSION"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-intents:$ESPRESSO_VERSION"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:$ESPRESSO_VERSION"

    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.1.2-alpha02'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.2-alpha02'

    androidTestImplementation("com.github.tomakehurst:wiremock:2.18.0") {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient'
        exclude group: 'asm', module: 'asm'
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    }

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Here Espresso's test:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class AddTraderActivityTest {
       @get:Rule
    var addTraderIntentTestRule: IntentsTestRule<AddTraderActivity> = IntentsTestRule(AddTraderActivity::class.java)

    @get:Rule
    var wireMockRule = WireMockRule(wireMockConfig().port(8082))
```

But I get error:

```
Started running tests

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/http/impl/client/HttpClientBuilder;
at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.http.HttpClientFactory.createClient(HttpClientFactory.java:53)
at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.http.ProxyResponseRenderer.<init>(ProxyResponseRenderer.java:58)
at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.core.WireMockApp.buildStubRequestHandler(WireMockApp.java:131)
at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.WireMockServer.<init>(WireMockServer.java:73)
at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.junit.WireMockRule.<init>(WireMockRule.java:43)
at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.junit.WireMockRule.<init>(WireMockRule.java:39)
at com.myproject.tm.android.activity.AddTraderActivityTest.<init>(AddTraderActivityTest.kt:70)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:217)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:266)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:263)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4.run(AndroidJUnit4.java:104)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at androidx.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:56)
at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:389)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1879)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.myproject.tm.android.debug.test-1/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.myproject.tm.android.debug-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.myproject.tm.android.debug.test-1/lib/arm, /data/app/com.myproject.tm.android.debug-2/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
... 34 more
Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder
at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
... 35 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available


Tests ran to completion.
```

Comment: @Onik Not help. Same error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/http/impl/client/HttpClientBuilder;